# find all directory with same name & remove all contents in centos

Tags: centos, find

I have 100 joomla website in my server I want to clean all of joomla cache folders.
I need a command to do this:

**1-** find all directories with "cache" name

if I search in for example "/home/demo/" directory

it find the "cache" directory in maximum one deeper level, like :

```
/home/demo/ddf3e/

/home/demo/awda2/
```

Not deeper than this

**2-** clean all files & directories inside of "cache"s directories

Only the contents to be remove **not itself**

**3-** creat an "index.html" file in all "cache"s directories

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most POSIX way to do this is probably to use the `find` command with multiple `-exec` options.

***Update:*** A fully POSIX solution is at the end of this post.

You can locate nested directories named "cache" under the `/home/demo` path like so:

```
find /home/demo -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -name cache
```

- `mindepth` and `maxdepth` values of `2` restrict the search to immediate child directories
- `-type d` designates that you only want to find directories
- `-name cache` tells it to only return matches that are named exactly "cache"

You can then use the `-exec` option to perform actions based on matched results. For example, if you wanted to run `ls` to list the contents of each matched cache directory:

```
find /home/demo -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -name cache -exec ls {} \;
```

- `-exec` calls the following command that follows it (`ls`) for each match
- `{}` returns the value of the match (in this case the path to the cache directory)
- `\;` tells it to perform the command one time for each match

So if you want to delete the contents of the directory, you can replace the `ls` command above with an appropriate `rm` statement—something like `sh -c 'rm "{}"/*'`

**Example (DO NOT RUN THIS):**

```
find /home/demo -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d -name cache -exec sh -c 'rm "{}"/* 2>/dev/null' \;
```

In the above example `sh -c` is used to allow for shell expansion of the `/*` to match nested files (that's not very POSIX though). You could then add another `-exec` as well to create an additional file.

**Example (DO NOT RUN THIS):**

```
 find /home/demo -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d -name cache -exec sh -c 'rm "{}"/* 2>/dev/null' \; -exec touch "{}/index.html" \;
```

In the above example two `-exec` options are used together. The second one, which creates a nested `index.html` file, only runs if the first `-exec` command completes successfully.

It's maybe better to split this into multiple find commands, though—one to match and remove the files, and another to create the `index.html`.

**Example (DO NOT RUN THIS):**

```
find /home/demo -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -wholename "/home/demo/*/cache/*" -exec rm -rf "{}" \;
find /home/demo -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d -name cache -exec touch "{}/index.html" \;
```

In the first statement:

- `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` of `3` only matches children of children
- `-wholename "/home/demo/*/cache/*"` provides a match to children of the target cache directories

The second statement then creates the `index.html` files.

If I understood your question correctly, then that command pair ***probably*** does what you're looking for. But read it carefully and make sure you fully understand it before using it.

I recommend prefixing any `rm` and `touch` commands with the `echo` command before running anything. That should let you have a dry run to see what it's doing.

**Example (safe dry run using `echo`):**

```
find /home/demo -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -wholename "/home/demo/*/cache/*" -exec echo rm -rf "{}" \;
find /home/demo -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d -name cache -exec echo touch "{}/index.html" \;
```

**Update - Fully POSIX Solution (but harder to read):**

For a fully POSIX equivalent (no `mindepth`/`maxdepth`/`wholename`) you can use a positive/negative `-path` combination using `find`'s internal globbing.

It's significantly easier if you `cd` into your working tree first, as you won't have to count the leading directories for your glob patterns.

```
cd /home/demo
find . -path "./*/cache/*" ! -path "./*/*/*/*" -exec echo rm -rf {} \;
find . -type d -path "./*/cache" ! -path "./*/*/*" -exec echo touch {}/index.html \;
```

*Remove the `echo` statements if you get the expected result.*

Comment: I completely forgot about the `-delete` option. [ilkkachu's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/309218/189192) is a far better choice for content removal. But I would recommend against using find with shell expansion (e.g. `find */cache`) in a script unless it's a one-off or you know your target shell settings.

Comment: `-delete` and `-min/maxdepth` aren't found in all versions of `find`, which is why I specifically mentioned GNU find. Good point on the glob, better use `./*` here, too.

Comment: @ilkkachu good point on `-min/maxdepth`. I've updated the post with what I believe to be a fully POSIX solution. Preferable to avoid any specific version options where we can.

Comment: This was a great education.
You gave me a lot of help and I owe you.

Answer (score 2):

So, if I got it right, you want to find e.g. `/home/demo/foo/cache` for all values of `foo`. Since you don't need to look in deeper levels, it's rather simple.

(1) You can list them with a shell glob:

```
$ cd /home/demo
$ echo */cache
```

To guard against funny names like those starting with a dash (`-foo`), we'd better use `./*`. Also, in bash, you can also make the glob include names starting with a dot by using `shopt -s dotglob`.

(2) Find and delete the files inside the directories (with GNU find, `-mindepth 1` keeps it from matching the directories themselves):

```
$ shopt -s dotglob
$ find ./*/cache -mindepth 1                          # list them
./awda2/cache/foo
[...]
$ find ./*/cache -mindepth 1 -delete                  # delete them...
```

You could also use just `rm`, but with a huge amount of files you might run past the limit for command line length.

```
$ rm -r ./*/cache/*
```

(3) Create or copy a file to all of them (`touch` creates an empty file):

```
$ for dir in ./*/cache ; do touch "$dir/index.html" ; done
$ for dir in ./*/cache ; do cp index.html.model  "$dir/index.html" ; done
```

(If there's a *file* (not directory) named `cache`, you'll get a harmless error about that.)

Comment: You started with globs, why not finish with them? `rm -rf ./*/cache/*`

Comment: @Centimane, Mostly because I originally ignored dotglob for simplicity, so any dotfiles in the cache directories would be left there. Another reason is that the command line length may be limited, and with a hundreds of dirs and files you might hit that. Depends on the system though, the two Linux systems I checked had the limit at 128 kB and 2 MB. The latter should be enough for a while. Also `find` came first to mind. ;) But I'll admit, that would remove the requirement for `-mindepth`